# How to print out bytes from binary file in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, binary

My print statement keeps throwing error, don't really understand what is going on.

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits

readByte :: String -> IO [Word8]
readByte fp = do
    contents <- BS.readFile fp
    return $ Prelude.take 5 $ unpack contents

main :: IO ()
main = do
    input <- readByte "DATA.BIN"
    print "Byte 0: " ++ [input!!0]
```

Getting the below error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[()]' with actual type `IO ()'
In the return type of a call of `print'
In the first argument of `(++)', namely `print "Byte 0: "'
```

Comment: A note on terminology.  `print` isn't "throwing [an] error", that would imply you are executing the program.  What is happening is the compiler is emitting a type checking error regarding the print statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell is parsing `print "Byte 0: " ++ [input!!0]` as `(print "Byte 0: ") ++ [input!!0]`, which is probably not what you intended. You might want

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    input <- readByte "DATA.BIN"
    putStrLn $ "Byte 0: " ++ show (input!!0)
```

instead

Comment: If I store input!!0 into a variable first and then use it in the putStrLn, I get "Couldn't match type `Word8' with `IO a0'" error.

Comment: Doing this databasetype <- input!!0 to assign the variable and then Prelude.putStrLn $ "DBType: " ++ show (databasetype) to print out. Getting the "Couldn't match type `Word8' with `IO a0'" error.

Comment: @Vlam Ah. So you will want to have `let databasetype = input!!0` for the assignment. `<-` actually is part of do-notation, which is something different. I recommend you read up on do-notation a bit.